# Link two Scatter charts in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

Based on the [Bokeh docs](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/linking.html#linking-behavior), it is possible to link two scatter plots created using the `plotting` interface:

```
s1 = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, title=None, tools=TOOLS)
s1.circle(x='Elevation', y='Aspect', source=src)

s2 = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, title=None, tools=TOOLS)
s2.circle(x='Elevation', y='Slope', source=src)
```

However, I'd like to do this with the Scatter chart, so that I can take advantage of automatic styling (e.g. colouring by a 3rd column). Is this possible? What I have right now, which *doesn't* work, is:

```
s1 = Scatter(df_samp, x='Elevation', y='Horizontal_Distance_To_Roadways', color='Cover_Type', plot_height=400, plot_width=400, source=src, tools=TOOLS)
s2 = Scatter(df_samp, x='Elevation', y='Aspect', color='Cover_Type', plot_height=400, plot_width=400, source=src, tools=TOOLS)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bokeh.charts` API, including `Scatter` has been deprecated and removed. The first code above, using the stable and supported `bokeh.plotting` API is the correct way to proceed in all cases now and in the future.

If you want to colormap based on additional columns, this is possible using various transforms:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html#transforming-data